I Can't sign in with HtmlContext.Session in .Net 8.0
I can not sign in with using htmlcontext.session, it redirects me again in log in page. I have searched many articles in online but nothing solved my problem and I do not want to use JWT Token for this. Project videos which I work on it, recorded 2 years ago and trainer used FormsAuthentication class for session but now I cant use it. Probably because of it was updated but unfortunately, I could not solve it.
//Here is my .program cs codes
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Admin p)
{
    MvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();

    var adminValues = mvcContext.Admins.FirstOrDefault
        (x => x.UserName == p.UserName && x.Password == p.Password);


    if (adminValues != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserName", p.UserName);
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Password", p.Password);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "AdminCategory");
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}

// and here is Controller
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();

        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("mssqlconnection");

        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


        //Session
        builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".NetCore.Session";
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });


        //Authentication
        builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "Login";
            options.LoginPath = "/Login/Index";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/Index";
        });


        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/ErrorPage/Page404");
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "Default",
            pattern: "{controller=Category}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }



}


You have to use HttpContext.SignInAsync to sing in of specified scheme. Test this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-8.0
